# How to set multiple condition for UITextField in shouldChangeCharactersIn in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

I am creating a Quiz kind of application. Where user have need to give input in `UITextField`. So I have to check for below conditions:

1. Restrict User to take only numbers and $ (`Like "0123456789$"`).
2. Add Commas in textfield.
3. `$` should come only one time in textfield value and that too after any number. It means User can't start input from `$`.
4. After `$`, if User will give any number input, then I have to display popup like "Number format is incorrect".

Here is my code :

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{


//Solution for 1st condition

let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789$").inverted

        let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)

        let filtered = components.joined(separator: "")

        if filtered == string {
            return true
        } else {
            if string == "." {
                let countdots = textField.text!.components(separatedBy:".").count - 1
                if countdots == 0 {
                    return true
                }else{
                    if countdots > 0 && string == "." {
                        return false
                    } else {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
    }



//Solution for 2nd condition

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0


        if let groupingSeparator = formatter.groupingSeparator {

            if string == groupingSeparator {
                return true
            }


            if let textWithoutGroupingSeparator = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: groupingSeparator, with: "") {
                var totalTextWithoutGroupingSeparators = textWithoutGroupingSeparator + string
                if string == "" { // pressed Backspace key
                    totalTextWithoutGroupingSeparators.characters.removeLast()
                }
                if let numberWithoutGroupingSeparator = formatter.number(from: totalTextWithoutGroupingSeparators),
                    let formattedText = formatter.string(from: numberWithoutGroupingSeparator) {

                    textField.text = formattedText
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

How to set multiple conditions within `UITextField shouldChangeCharactersIn` method. Please help me to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create 2 validation methods, return true/false from both conditions, and then check both true or not, then only make it continue or give proper message.

```
func validationCase1(text:String) -> Bool {
 // validate scenario 1.
 return isValidated.
}

func validateCase2(text:String) -> Bool {
 // validate scenario 2.
 return isValidated.
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

 var isValidatedFirst = validateCase1(string);
 var isValidatedSecond = validateCase2(string);

 if(isValidatedFirst == isValidatedSecond == true){
  // pass
 }
 else if(isValidatedFirst == false){
  // show message for first
 }
 else if(isValidatedSecond == false){
  // show message for second
 }
}
```

Comment: What I have to return in shouldChangeCharactersIn method?

Comment: Is there any other way to write this line code 'if(isValidatedFirst == isValidatedSecond == true){' as getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your 2nd point but rest of the things can easily be achieved by using simple Regular expressions. Here is an example:

```
private func regexMatch(string: String, pattern: String) -> Bool {
    if let range = string.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
        let subString = string[range]
        if subString == string {
            return  true
        }
    }

    return false
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let result = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? string
    if regexMatch(string: result, pattern: "[0-9]+\\$*[0-9]*") || result.count == 0 {
        if regexMatch(string: result, pattern: "[0-9]+\\${0,1}") == false && result.count != 0 {
            print("Number format is incorrect")
        }
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This code snippet will only accept digits and '$' as inputs of UITextField. '$' cannot be the first character and any number after '$' will result in the error message to be printed.

I hope this will give you enough clarity to customise it to fit your needs.

**Update:**

To restrict user from entering anything after '$' and to enforce only one occurrence of '$' replace

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

with

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let result = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? string
    if regexMatch(string: result, pattern: "[0-9]+\\${0,1}") || result.count == 0 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your code now '$' cannot be the first character and any number after '$', but how can I prevent user not to enter any number after $?

Comment: User should use $ only once, please help me on this.

Comment: I figured that but my original answer was based on your requirements mentioned in your question. Anyways I have updated my answer to include your points.